html-to-image returns a darker image compare to front-end component
Using Next.js 14 and html-to-image library.
The item icon, which is implemented with img tag seems to be okay.
But others get darker.
html component 

Image downloaded from using html-to-image 

  const handleSaveAsImage = async () => {
    const image = await toPng(boxRef.current);

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = image;
    link.download = `${itemName}`;
    link.target = "_blank"; // Open in a new tab
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

      <Box
        ref={boxRef}
        sx={{
          position: "relative",
          padding: 0,
          paddingTop: 1.5,
          paddingBottom: 2,
          minWidth: "261px",
          maxWidth: "271px",
          height: "auto",
          minHeight: 180,
          backgroundColor: "background.quaternary",
          borderRadius: 2,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          border: "1px solid rgba(155,155,155,0.16)",
          justifyContent: "start",
        }}
      >
      ...
      </Box>

